# Facebook OpenGraph API get Job or company name from user id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to use the opengraph explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
to read the current job or company name where the user is currently working at. to be more specific I want to get the field in the screenshot:
http://justinsblog.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/18/2013/03/1-add-fan-page.jpg

After reading and searching the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/) i've tried: {user-id}?fields=work but it doesnt seem to work and just returns the given user-id

I hope anyone can help?

Comment: Did the user grant permission for you to read their work?

Comment: I'm not a friend with the user-id I tested and could see where he work when visiting his profile page directly via facebook with my account

Comment: for example I did a get request to this endpoint: v2.11/10101640953722381?fields=id,name,work

the id here is from mark zuckerberg but the returned response is the following:
{
  "id": "10101640953722381",
  "name": "Mark Zuckerberg"
}

I've expected to get his current work

Comment: Just because you can see something on facebook.com doesn't mean you can see it through the API. The user needs to grant `user_work_history` to your app for you to access their work history.

Comment: alright thank you. so it's not possible to get the work information with open graph api without user granting access for a facebook app

Comment: That is correct.